# Don't remove the edited text from the window if an edit cannot be applied anymore to a chat message

Tags: feature-request, chat, editor

If you entered a message in chat and then noticed you want to word it differently or add something, but you take too long to edit it, you will receive a message from SO that tells you

> It's too late to edit this message.

It would be better if you don't remove the text from the edit window in that case, so that the text isn't lost.